# Can my employer watch my remote desktop session?

Tags: rdp, remote, desktop

I have a vps that I would like to connect to from work using remote desktop, is it possible for my employer to see my rdp session? What exactly does my employer see/know in regard to my rdp connection to my vps?

Thanks

Comment: If you have to ask this question, it's likely you ought not be doing whatever it is you're doing on your VPS anyway.

Comment: You could just not browse porn at work. ;-)

Comment: Here's the thing... say I need to log into my bank to pay a bill on my lunch break, or view an informational blog that websense blocks for whatever reason, instead of using company resources I would rather rdp to my vps...

Comment: I'd like a monkey dressed as a cowboy who gets me drinks at work but you can't do everything you want at work can you?

Comment: Well even if you RDP, you'd still be using your company resources, wouldn't you?

Comment: Its no different than someone taking off early from work to deal with their kids or a doctor visit or whatever.. sometimes you just need or have things to take care of and need to use company resources to do so.

Comment: It is different. If using RDP to access your VPS violates company policy then your analogy would better be, "taking the company car without permission to take my kids to the doctor." Sure, you're doing something you need to do, but you're doing it in a way which is illegal. Around here network policy violations get people fired.

Comment: "I can't do anything at work that's not work related, SO NEITHER CAN YOU"

Comment: @daniel ball I've searched through the employee agreement and see nothing that remotely (so to speak) mentions it so Its definitely not as if I'm trying to circumvent company policy

Comment: @rigil If it's truly something you need to do and can't find anything policy related then appeal to the powers that be and get the WebSense config changed.  I watched person after person get fired for 5 years for trying to do exactly what you're asking here.  Is it really worth that?

Comment: If you must be able to do personal stuff from work, why not simply get yourself a phone/tablet with a data plan.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible?

Yes, it's certainly possible, and in a way in which you'd never know he could see you. But it's got nothing to do with RDP or your VPS specifically, just your desktop, it'd be the same for your browsing/Excel etc. If he wants to see it the technology is there yes. It would also be very easy for him to stop you RDPing to it too.

The question I have is why are you trying to circumvent existing IT policy?

Answer (score 0):

If they have admin rights on the server you're remoting into, there is an option that would let them see exactly the same thing you are looking at on your screen. I would assume you're doing work on that server so you have nothing to worry about, right? RIGHT?

Comment: My employer has no admin rights on my vps, as it is.... my vps.

Comment: If your employer has admin rights on the machine from which you're remotely accessing another machine, yes, it's possible to see what you're doing. And he'd have a right to. As the owner of the business (or an authorized administrator of the machines) he has a right to monitor how the company's assets are being used (at least in the US)